# Java connection to SQL Server (Error)

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to connect to my SQL server many different way. I am using **jdbc4 driver for Microsoft SQL Server 2012**. I have input it in the build path. My confusion comes when I try to run my code as an android application. I get the following error when the code is ran.

```
 Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=5992, tid=5208
 fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

 JRE version:  (7.0_51-b13) (build )
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\LiL_Blevs11\Google Drive\CPET 490\Database\workspace\MedRecords\hs_err_pid5992.log
```

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

```
package com.seniordesign.medrecords;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        // Load the NetDirect JDBC driver

        String driverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc";

        Class.forName(driverName);

        // Create a connection to the database

        String computer = "LIL_BLEVS-PC";

        String serverName = "SQLEXPRESS";

        String serverPort = "1433";

        String database = computer + "\"" + serverName + ":" + serverPort;

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + database;

        String username = "username";

        String password = "password";

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        System.out.println("Successfully Connected to the database!");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Could not find the database driver "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Could not connect to the database "
                + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your class name driver does not seem correct, change to:

```
driverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

and make sure the driver jar is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure if the driver is incorrect as isah says, but your error seems pretty much like [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030111/fatal-error-invalid-layout-of-java-lang-string-at-value)

So I think you are forgetting one step: Run As -> Android Application