# Inside Eclipse Android project run Java classes with main(String[] args) as Java Application causes "Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Inside Eclipse Android project how to run Java classes with main(String[] args) as Java Application ?

```
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // some dummy operations here, possibly including 
        // System.out.print(string);
    }
}
```

I get error

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=6748, tid=6676
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version: 7.0_11-b21
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Workspaces\ADT-Bundle\FMonPianoApp\hs_err_pid6748.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I use `main()` for small tests (without JUnit)

Comment: I suggest you keep your Android code separate from your non-Android code... it's likely to make things much simpler.

Comment: Is the project defined as an Android project?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In case of an **Android** project, you have to **remove** *Android Lib* from the launch configuration for that specific class. Use the "walkthrough" below as a guide.

- **Project**->**Properties**->**Run/Debug Settings**;
- **Select your Class** and click "**Edit**";
- Open the tab "**Classpath**" and **remove** *Android Lib* from "*Bootstrap Entries*";
- **Apply** everything and **Run** the class again.

**OR**

You can get past this by using the `Run As -> Android Application`. Possibly check the Run configuration for other issues.

Hope this helps

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210088/1250107)

Comment: @PaulVerest Mark the answer correct if it helped you. So that others can come to know which is the correct answer of the question.

Comment: Only after 10 min when SO allows

Comment: The best answer I have ever found the last day! Thank you!