# How to run Android unit test (from android gradle plugin 1.1) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit, gradle

We are already having sources under `src/main/java` and gradle build that is occasionally launched from Eclipse and every few minutes after commits on CI server. [Gradle for Eclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/) helps [a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107014/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gradle-build-system-for-android-with-eclipse).

Android gradle plugin 1.1.0-rc1 (2015/02/02) comes with ["*special version of android.jar that is compatible with popular mocking frameworks (e.g. Mockito)*".](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

I wonder if it is possible to squeeze JUnit testing for Android within Eclipse to make those who sticks to Eclipse to actually start using unit tests more.

**How to run Android unit test in Eclipse?**

I know that for Android project any Java class with `main` [can be launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252516/inside-eclipse-android-project-run-java-classes-with-mainstring-args-as-java) in Eclipse if the Android Lib is removed. I guessed now similar finer configuration is needed with this 
"*special version of android.jar*"

UPDATE:

Not to be confused with [Android test projects: Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395216/creating-an-android-junit-test-project-in-eclipse)

So far I created new Java project and referenced Android project.
I can use and test Java classes from it and it dependencies including support library, but not any classes from Android framework (coming from `android.jar`)

Comment: Also raised as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459408