# android calling method from library project force closed

Tags: android, methods, android-activity

Hi I have an android library project A. Its Main Activity contains method abc(String).When I am trying to call this method from other project after integrating project A,It force closed. I used the code

```
 MainActivity a=new MainActivity();
 a.abc("");
```

Am I do the right way to call a method from library project activity from other project?? please help me I am new to android,thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the `abc` function and/or some LogCat output?

Comment: Your project and library project both are at same location ?

Comment: Provide your logcat here.

Comment: Don't instantiate `Activity`s manually...

Comment: see this..,are you getting like this error..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030111/fatal-error-invalid-layout-of-java-lang-string-at-value

Comment: have you added the jars and required import statements

Answer (score 3):

You should not instantiate a Activity class. Activity has a lifecycle and you should declare the same in manifest and use `startActivity(intent)`.

Check **Declaring library components in the manifest file**

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Once declared you can start the Activity.

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Quoting Raghav Sood

By treating an Activity as a normal Java class, you end up with a null context. As most methods in an Activity are called on its Context, you will get a null pointer exception, which is why your app crashes.

Instead, move all such methods which need to be called from other classes into a Utility class which accepts a valid context in its constructor, and then use that context in the methods to do the work.

Comment: @prince where did i suggest `getInstance`. Did you read the post in full. read Raghav Sood's answer not the other one

Comment: I used to call method in my oncreate . now how can i declare it as a class??

Comment: @prince did you get the gist of my post. you can't call a method of another activity class. You can start another activity. If you want to call a method use a utils class put the method there then you can create an instance of that class and call the method. Raghav Sood's answer is the best in the link i provided. I don't why the other one got upvoted which popped that in from of the second

Comment: I got the the points. But I used a method in my oncreate called pop() which used to popup the oncreate window and i declared this method in the same activity.As you said when I am uses a class file for declaring this method it shows errors because my activity contents are there in my method. this is the problem i faced now

Comment: @prince i am lost as to what you are saying. I cannot understand. Good luck