# Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am creating an Android mobile app in Eclipse Luna and everything was working fine. Then I received the following error. I have tried running my project as an Android Application, editing the debug settings, and removing Android Lib from the Bootstrap Entries, but nothing has worked. Does anyone have anything else that I can try?

I only receive the error message when I run my program as there are no errors throughout the program until runtime. The program also runs as a Java application but won't work on an android application. When I installed the android SDK plugin that's when the error occurred but until the plugin was installed the program ran. My error message in full is:

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
#    A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#    Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:126), pid=4632, tid=4988
#    fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
#    JRE version:  (8.0_25-b18) (build )
#    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
#    Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on   client     versions of Windows
#
#    An error report file with more information is saved as:
#    C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Final Year      Project\IndependentRetailers\hs_err_pid4632.log
#
#    If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13030111/2670892

Comment: Sadly I tried these solutions and nothing worked. Not sure if this has caused the issue but the problem occurred after I installed sdk manager tools for Eclipse. Would that have had any affect on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of an Android project, you have to **remove** Android Lib from the launch configuration for that specific class. Use the "walkthrough" below as a guide.

**Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings;**

**Select your Class** and click "**Edit**";

Open the tab "**Classpath**" and **remove** Android Lib from "Bootstrap Entries";

**Apply** everything and **Run** the class again.

OR

You can get past this by using the **Run As -> Android Application.** Possibly check the Run configuration for other issues.

Hope this helps