# Java runtime issue, but build project there is no error

Tags: java, android

When I build my  project, there is no error, but when I run the project,there is a error come out as follows:

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:127), pid=8228, tid=6992
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_45-b15) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eclipse_Projects\LookAtMe2_source\Test.LookAtMe.Data\hs_err_pid8228.log
```

In the hs_err_pid8228.log file:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:127), pid=8228, tid=6992
 fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
JRE version:  (8.0_45-b15) (build )
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Window
```

Comment: after  I rebuild the project and chose the run as Android project,there is an error as follow:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Run As -> Android Application
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030111/fatal-error-invalid-layout-of-java-lang-string-at-value).

Comment: After I rebuild the project and Run as Android ,there is a error that: 
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opencv/R$attr; LookAtMe  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Comment: Go to Project/properties and Java Build Path and unchecked the Android Private Libraries From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray