# j2objc Error in Translate to Objective C

Tags: java, android, code-translation, j2objc

there is Android Source I Need to translate to Objective C

but it shows error :

```
java -Xbootclasspath:$J2OBJC_HOME/lib/jre_emul.jar -jar $J2OBJC_HOME/lib/j2objc.jar j2objcc

Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

#

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#

#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:127), pid=575, tid=4867

#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

#

# JRE version:  (8.0_51-b16) (build )

# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)

# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

#

# An error report file with more information is saved as:

# /Users/emaar/AndroidStudioProjects/TestBuild/app/src/main/java/com/emaar/app/testbuild/hs_err_pid575.log

#

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

#

Abort trap: 6
```

any things set (JDK 8, Maven, SDK, Android Studio, Gradle, J2OBJC, ...)

how to solve it ?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the Java code that causes this problem with translation. Better again, try to isolate the single line within that code block which causes this issue.

Comment: This also looks similar to this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030111/fatal-error-invalid-layout-of-java-lang-string-at-value

Comment: @brunobowden The similar question Doesn't help to fix it ...

Answer (score 1):

"j2objcc" is not a Java source file. If you run your command without it, the valid usage and flags for j2objc will be displayed.

Comment: can you help me by explain more or some thing else ?

Comment: I'd start with the instructions in http://j2objc.org/docs/Getting-Started.html. Even if you are familiar with them, they will help verify your installation is correctly setup.

Comment: I get started with http://j2objc.org/docs/Getting-Started.html but it doesn't help to fix errors