# How to search file and grab the field needed?

Tags: java, eclipse, readfile

New to java. Now I am trying to open, read and search a file, but Eclipse is giving me an error. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {            
      BufferedReader doc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Grad\\Project\\test.csv"));
      /* String userInput;    */
      String docCont = new String();
      while ((docCont = doc.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(docCont);
        doc.close();
      }
    } catch(IOException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The code compiles, but when I try to run it I get this:

> ```
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=5036, tid=4704
> fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
>
> JRE version:  (7.0_67-b01) (build )
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
> C:\Users\ximinmi\workspace\OldImageReveal\hs_err_pid5036.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> ```

Any idea what this is about? Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything informative in that `hs_err_pid5036.log` file?  What happens if you try to compile and run this from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Your close statement is in your while loop, so on the first iteration, you will no longer be able to read from your reader. Write this instead:

```
BufferedReader doc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Grad\\Project\\test.csv"));
String docCont = new String();
while ((docCont = doc.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(docCont);
}
doc.close();
```

Comment: OK. I'm not sure, as my observation could be one of many errors. What does the file at `C:\Users\ximinmi\workspace\OldImageReveal\hs_err_pid5036.log` say?

Comment: Even better would be to use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), but that shouldn't cause the fatal error OP is seeing.  I suspect this is a red herring.

Comment: ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0130d400):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=4704, stack(0x00ce0000,0x00d30000)]

Stack: [0x00ce0000,0x00d30000],  sp=0x00d2f970,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x190494]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18a116]
V  [jvm.dll+0x35d7a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x35e06]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4465d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4490e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x92f8a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x9333b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x13fa31]

Comment: @frenchDolphin: The error message I put in the post followed by the one above.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15840413/3761440) seems to suggest that it is a problem with your run configuration. Go to Run -> Run Configurations